# R: select columns in matrix without col. `X`

Tags: r

How can I select all columns in a matrix *without* some subset of columns (by name)?

Here I would like to select all but `foo`

```
m = as.matrix(1:4)
dim(m) <- c(2,2)
colnames(m) = c('foo', 'bar')

     foo bar
[1,]   1   3
[2,]   2   4

m[, all-but-`foo`] # ???
```

In the real script my matrix has many columns and I would like to select all of them but one or two. I do not want to specify explicitly the columns I want to select, by rather those that I don't want at the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `%in%` operator

```
m[ , ! colnames(m) %in% c('foo') ]
[1] 3 4
```

Add as many names as you like to the `c` vector. In this example it appears as a vector because you have only one column returned.

#### Better example

```
m <- matrix( 1 , nrow = 3 , ncol = 6 )
colnames( m ) <- letters[1:6]
m[ , ! colnames(m) %in% c('a','b') ]
     c d e f
[1,] 1 1 1 1
[2,] 1 1 1 1
[3,] 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible that inside `colnames` I use something like "self" instead of repeating the matrix variable name?

Comment: @JakubM. No it is not (as I understand what you mean - please elaborate if this is a problem).

Comment: if `m` were `a_very_long_name` then the line would look ugly when you have to put it both at the beginning of the line and inside `colnames`

Comment: @JakubM. ah ok. Just do `m <- myuglylongnamedthingymajig` then do the subset. `R` doesn't really make a copy in memory. Not immediately anyway....